# Update statement not working correctly. SQL

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

This is my code :

```
procedure TForm4.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);    
var      
    spinval, iVotes: integer;    
begin    
    if DBLookupComboBox1.Text = ' ' then    
    begin    
        ShowMessagePos('Please select a candidate.', 1000, 500);    
    end    
    else    
    begin    
        spinval := SpinEdit1.value;    
        ADOQuery1.Active := false;    
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Update Candidate_table set votes = ''' +
            inttostr(spinval + Candidatetable.fieldbyname('Votes').AsInteger) + 
            ''' where Name = ''' + DBLookupComboBox1.Text + '''';    
        ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;    
        ADOQuery1.Active := false;    
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select * from Candidate_table';    
        ADOQuery1.Active := true;    
        MessageDlgPos('Thank you for voting. You will be logged out.' , mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, 1000, 500);    
        Form4.Hide;    
        Form2.Show;    
    end    
end;
```

My problem is that it does count up each time I click this button (The specific row and column "Votes" is set to defualt value of 0, every time I click on the button it must plus the spinedit value with the value of the column "Votes".)

Now with this code it is just replacing the values.
What did I do wrong ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: After the line `ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := `, add a new line with `ShowMessage(ADOQuery1.SQL.Text);` and read the SQL it displays. It's wrong. You have quotes where they don't belong, which wouldn't happen if you would **listen to people** and start using parameters. If you refuse to listen to what people tell you in their answers, they stop answering you pretty fast because it's a waste of their time. *STOP using `+` to build your SQL!*

Comment: @Ken Sorry I've never worked with "Paremeters" My teacher taught me to use + signs whenever I want to use an Edit box or Spinedit etc...But thanks I will try to adapt this

Comment: If you suspect there's something wrong with your SQL, then you need to look at your SQL. Use the debugger to inspect the value of SQL.Text. Does it contain what you expected it to? Does it contain what you expect it to *every time*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be clearer, safer, and faster if you use parameters. Also, you can refer to the old column value right in the query, rather than getting the old value from your current query.

Try this:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 
    'Update Candidate_table set votes = votes + :number where Name = :candidate';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('number').Value := spinval;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('candidate').Value := DBLookupComboBox1.Text;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: +1 Parameters are your friend. They make it much easier to write and more importantly READ queries. and save a whole world of pain with SQL injection, and simply handling strings with `'`s in them, such as O'Connor

Comment: OMW....Thanks soooooo much this worked perfectly!!!! thanks for teaching me that =) Helped a lot.